# Why does Websphere Process Server WSDL import add a level of indirection

Tags: wsdl, mapping, websphere-7, websphere-process-server

We have a web service that returns and object (for example `CustomerResponse`) which has a property that is a list (for example `ListOfCustomers`).

When we import this into WPS it creates a hierarchy of `CustomerResponse`, which has an object `ArrayOfListOfCustomers`, which in turn contains the actual `ListOfCustomers`.

Why does WPS add this extra layer? is there any way to turn it off?

Comment: When you say you import it, you mean the IID, or the admin console?